# Does a 5V Switch-Mode Power Supply need a voltage regulator to power a 5V device?

Tags: arduino, switch-mode-power-supply

Since I'm using a 5V SMPS to power the device, it got me thinking if I even needed a voltage regulator. Is powering my device directly to the SMPS advisable? Is there a better way to go about powering my device?

I'm making a fire alarm and these are the components I used. It's composed of two gas sensors (MQ2, MQ7), and a temperature & humidity sensor (DHT22). It uses two microcontrollers, ATMEGA328P and ESP32. When I made the prototype, I supplied 5V to the breadboard using a laptop USB port. I also powered the esp32 module with another USB port from the same laptop. I never actually used the LM317 voltage regulator. I was required to create a combinational circuit (fire alert circuit) and use an atmega chip, the esp32 is used for wifi. For the PCB, I replaced the gas sensors with a single AGS10, and the temperature & humidity sensor with an AHT21. I haven't tested this PCB yet because I'm currently in the process of designing it. Which is when I had this question.

[image: fire alarm schematic]

Comment: What is the output voltage ripple of your switching power supply? Can your circuit tolerate that ripple? That is the essential question you need to answer.

Comment: I haven't bought the switching power supply yet so I can't tell. Would decoupling capacitors be enough to smoothen the output of the power supply? I'll buy one first and get back to this.

Comment: If the power supply is "generic" in the sense of not being a power supply for this or that particular device, then a reputable manufacturer would give specs regarding ripple. If you want to buy a power supply, but don't know the ripple, how would you decide if it were appropriate or not? A less than reputable supplier will hope you don't care. Will decoupling capacitors be enough to reduce the ripple to acceptable levels? Maybe, but it might be the case that you would need such large capacitors you would overload on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot power your device the way you have designed it since the output voltage of a linear regulator must be lower than the input, and in the case of LM317, it must be at least ~1.5V lower.  So no way to take 5V in and generate 5.04V out of the regulator.

You have a couple of options:

1. Get a 7V or higher power supply and use the lm317. Or a 6V power supply and a regulator with a <1V drop out.
2. Use a 5V power supply directly.

In this case, I'd probably keep the linear regulator since you have various analog sensors that might be sensitive to noise.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've draw it, it won't work properly. To get 5V out of an LM317 you should give it something like 8V at the input. You don't get 5V out for 5V in. Even if the regulator was an LDO type, the regulator could not perform its function since it will need a bit of headroom to get rid of noise and little dips.

As to whether a SMPS can be used directly- it depends on the quality of 5V supply you need compared to what you have.

If you need a very quiet supply for an analog rail you might be better to use a 5V SMPS and use an LDO to regulate down to something like 3.3 VDC. The gas sensors are relatively crude devices and probably the power quality is not very important to getting a relatively noise-free and roughly accurate reading. The DHT22 has a digital interface and contains a microcontroller (likely without a voltage regulator) and separate thermistor and polymer capacitor sensing elements. Chances are that if the temperature reading is stable  it will be relatively accurate, but you can compare readings with the SMPS and a very low-noise supply to see if there is any difference. The humidity is, again, a relatively crude measurement so probably not very sensitive to PS accuracy and noise. So I suspect this particular circuit will work fine with a decent SMPS.